# What is the use of expand_path

Tags: ruby

I came across the following line of code

```
@base_dir = File.expand_path(".")
```

Can anyone tell what the use is of `expand_path` and the `"."` as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.expand_path()` receives a directory (like "." that denotes the current directory) and returns the absolute path of that same directory.

So in this case it will return the absolute path of the current working directory.

Look here the documentation of this method:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html